# Icecast on virtualbox ubuntu through router

Tags: ubuntu, router, icecast

I'm using icecast2 server on my virtual ubuntu machine and i want it to become available to connect by entering myIP:port, but i have router. I made port forwarding settings on my router to connect to inner IP if asking for outerIP:port. What settings i should do in virtualbox to make my server available to connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your VirtualBox network settings for that VM.

If you have set the networking up for bridging and have forwarded your ports directly to the VM, you're done.

If you are using NAT, then you need to forward ports from your host to the guest OS using the VirtualBox network panel.